# Cutting off an infinite matrix(Making a finite matrix from an infinite matrix)

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, infinite-matrices

Let's say that there is an infinite matrix **A**. How do you make a new finite matrix B, from the matrix **A**?

What I mean is that I want to get a finite matrix that best matches/**approximates** the original infinite matrix **A**. (So that we can easily analyze that matrix with computer)
(If **"Best match"** is ambiguous, let's start by "in terms of multiplication".)

If not every infinite matrix can be cut-off(Converting to finite matrix is so useless that it cannot represent the original matrix at all), than what conditions should the infinite matrix fit?

Comment: I think that's hard to answer without a preciser definition of "best match". An easy case is if almost all entries are like the identity, i.e. $A_{i,j} = \delta_{i,j}$  for almost all $i,j$ ($\delta_{i,j}=1$ iff $i=j$ and $0$ else). Then you can just "cut off" almost all columns and rows to obtain a finite matrix. This would correspond to the inclusion $GL(n,\mathbb R) \hookrightarrow GL(n+1,\mathbb R)$, which gives rise to the limit $GL(\mathbb R)$ ([which comes up in algebraic K-theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_K-theory#K1)).

Comment: @Babelfish Thank you for your kind explanation, but I have no idea about that General Linear something and algebraic K-theory(Other things came to my mind hopefully). What should I learn to understand that?

Comment: The limit of the general linear group, $GL(\mathbb R)$ is a way to multiply matrices of different sizes or even infinite matrices, if the relevant part of the infinite matrix happens in a finite 'region'. Consider the following: If you have two invertible square matrices $A$ and $B$ of different sizes, you might multiply them by adding $1$'s on the diagonal and $0$'s elsewhere, till they have the same size. Then you can multiply them. Though you have, for example, to identify the matrices $\begin{pmatrix}2&3\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}2&3&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: ... This is just an abstract way to define "cutting a matrix". Though it only works for matrices of the already mentioned form. If you aim for a more general situation, I suggest that you do not search for $GL(\mathbb R)$, since you propably need something else and won't benefit from it. Algebraic K-theory is a somewhat sofisticated theory.

Comment: @Babelfish Kind explanation! Thank you and I'll comment again when I understand your comment.

Comment: @Babelfish Got it. Thanks.

Comment: So is this what you wanted? If not you should try to specify your settings.

Comment: @Babelfish I think I'll have to specify the kind of object matrices like Operator matrices. Anyway your comments helped me much. Thanks.

Comment: @Babelfish Is there any orthogonal function system that has finite numbers of basis so that the vector representation of any function has finite number of components? (And of course the operator matrix too is finite)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81873/discussion-between-babelfish-and-kyhsgeekcode).

Comment: @Babelfish is $GL\mathbb R$ same with semi tensor product?

Comment: I have to admit that I don't know what a semi tensor product is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kinda depends on the properties of the infinite matrix / linear operator *(after all, $\bf A$ is nothing but the representation matrix $(\langle e_i,Ae_j\rangle)_{i,j\in\mathbb N}$ of your operator $A$ with respect to an orthonormal basis $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of your Hilbert space $\mathcal H$)* you are considering. For this, let $\Pi_n$ is the orthogonal projection $\sum_{j=1}^n\langle e_n,\cdot\rangle e_n$ onto the first $n$ elements of your orthonormal basis $e_1,\ldots,e_n$, so $\Pi_n {\bf A}\Pi_n$ is the upper left $n\times n$-block of $\bf A$ (and the rest of $\bf A$ is set to zero).

Now, for example: if $\bf A$ is [compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator_on_Hilbert_space), then $\Pi_n{\bf A}\Pi_n$ approximates ${\bf A}$ in the operator norm, e.g. $\|{\bf A}-\Pi_n{\bf A}\Pi_n\|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Even stronger, if $\bf A$ is a [Schatten class operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_class_operator) with $p\in [1,\infty)$, then the above approximation holds in the $p$-norm so $\|{\bf A}-\Pi_n{\bf A}\Pi_n\|_p\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Furthermore, these statements hold for all orthonormal bases of $A$ so you can choose any represenetation matrix of your operator $\bf A$ (e.g. $U{\bf A}U^\dagger$ for any unitary $U\in\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$ ).

Then again, your exact question was kinda vague to me so I'm not sure if this is what you were looking for - if I missed your point, I'm sorry.

Comment: I don't know anything about the Hilbert space, but I think you found my point and answered well.