# Iterations of a multivariable function

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

How do you define iterations of **multivariable functions**?

To be clear(example):

> If $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$
>
> How do you define
>
> $f \circ f$, or $f \circ \cdots \circ f$?

I admit that this question sounds **very odd**, but I think I need to define or learn of this. (Why? I want to generalize [this(Carleman matrix)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleman_matrix#General_Series) to multivariable functions to solve [this(Multivariable carleman matrix)](https://mathoverflow.net/q/309449/128168) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2896117/553404)(same but different sites) question!)

And I think this concept may be quite reasonable because there is a something like [multiplication of matrices that have different dimensions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885669/cutting-off-an-infinite-matrixmaking-a-finite-matrix-from-an-infinite-matrix#comment5959373_2885669)

My assumtion is that $f \circ f \cdots \circ f : \text{also  } \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I suppose you could define $\tilde f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ by $\tilde f(x,y) = (f(x,y),f(x,y))$, then investigate $f_n := f\circ \tilde f\circ \tilde f\circ\dots \circ \tilde f$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Worth trying!

Comment: There are definitely many possible versions... $F(x,y) =(0,f(x,y)); (f(x,y),f(x,y));$ or even $(f(x,y),f(y,x))$ (which is sort of a more ‘symmetric’ version of $f$). Which one you should consider depends highly on the property you want them to satisfy

Answer (score 0):

The composition is undefined as $$f \circ f=\mathbb{R}^2\xrightarrow{f}\mathbb{R}\xrightarrow{?}\underline{?}.$$ However if you have a function $\mathbb{R}^2\xrightarrow{F}\mathbb{R}^2,$ then we can easily form the composition.

Comment: You're definitely right! But I know that too... I want to "define" it. Anyway, it seems that and your answer is saying that it has not been defined formally.

Comment: @KYHSGeekCode: How could we define something that cannot exist? The only way to get-rid of the problem is change the co-domain (naturally or artificially).